# rxjava ObservableCreate with emitter vs rxrelay PublishRelay

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I'm a bit new to reactive programming so I want to start with explaining my use case and what I did, then the problem with my solution and what I think is the answer but I'm not sure.

So this is my use case:
I have an android app that tries to connect to a remote server.
When the user clicks on a button, I am trying to connect to this server with reactive programming, and I try to connect with serveral "connectors" so I iterate throgh them, until one of the connectors success.

So this is how I did it:

```
Disposable disposable = currentConnector.connect(ip)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap(fallbackDefaultConnector())
        .subscribeWith(connectionSubscriber);
```

this is `connectionSubscriber`:

```
new DisposableObserver<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull Boolean item) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Observable emits: " + item);
                if (item) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connected!");
                } else {
                    handleConnectionFailed();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "On Error" + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                handleConnectionFailed();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                closeConnectionProcedure();
            }
        };
```

this is an example for `currentConnector.connect(ip)` (please note the **timeout**):

```
@Override
public Observable<Boolean> connect(String ipAddress) {
    isConnected = false;
    client.setHost(ipAddress);

    Observable<Boolean> observable = client.connect
            .timeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    connectionEmitter = client.getConnectionEmitter();

    return observable;
}
```

**Now the tricky part** -> inside this connector, I save the `emitter` of the clients. why? becase the client redirects me to another pairing fragment for example.
this is how the `client.connect` looks like in the constructor **of the client**:

```
connect = new ObservableCreate<>(emitter -> {
    connectionEmitter = emitter;
    doConnect(host);
});
```

and when the `doConnect(host)` sucess inside the client, I send a message like this:

```
connectionEmitter.onNext(true);
connectionEmitter.onComplete();
```

and it works. when the client connects, everything is fine.
My problem is when the **connection failes on all connectors** or if the user get a **timeoutexception**. if it fails I send a failure like so:

```
connectionEmitter.onNext(false);
connectionEmitter.onComplete();
```

and indeed the user see a "failed connecting" message and it's ok.

**So what is the problem?**
***If it fails and the user tries to connect again, nothing happens!***
I researched it and *I saw that an emitter cannot emitt more events after the `observable` had an `onComplete` event or an `onError` event*.

So I have two thoughts about this-

1. maybe I am not using reactive programming correct for my use case?
2. maybe I need to implement it with `rxrelay` and with `PublishRealy`? If so, how can I save the **emitter** and do some more logic other then just `accept(value)`?

Answer (score 0):

The design choice to save the emitter seems wrong. Once the emitter is done emitting it should then be released for GC. Thats how the Rx was designed and if by any chance you need to redo the work then you should create a new instance of emitter or observable then you can observe this new instance.

Comment: even if I set the observable to null on the failure, it still cant emit again

Comment: do you create a new observable when you reconnect ??